# Changing treeview state images

Tags: c++, winapi, treeview

I'm (still) trying to figure out how to change state images of a treeview from the default +/- to an image of my choice.  I'm making progress but I've hit a wall.

I'm just trying to change the image when a branch is expanded.  When I use the below code, sometimes it changes and sometimes not.  It only acts as expected when I bounce back and forth a few times, not the first time.

I assume I'm missing a flag or haven't set something correctly?  Any tips?

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    if (wParam == IDC_TVWFILELIST) {
        LPNMTREEVIEW nmtv = (LPNMTREEVIEW) lParam;

        if (nmtv->hdr.code == TVN_ITEMEXPANDED) {
            TVITEM item = nmtv->itemNew;
            item.state = INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(4);
            TreeView_SetItem(pnl_tree.GetTreeview(), &item);
        }
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, of course when I post on SO I figure it out myself soon after!  Darn.  Guess it helps to talk it through. Anyway, for the next guy.

---

I've had this same problem at other places learning the winapi, especially with treeviews - if I neglect setting a certain member of a struct, I get strange behavior.

In this case, turns out that `item.stateMask = TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;` needed to be re-set.

Apparently it doesn't persist across [TreeView_SetItem()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which very concisely states "The TreeView_SetItem macro sets some or all of a tree-view item's attributes").

Working code, for me, with a bonus of expand/collapse handler (now I'm cooking with gas):

```
if (wParam == IDC_TVWFILELIST) {
    LPNMTREEVIEW nmtv = (LPNMTREEVIEW) lParam;

    if (nmtv->hdr.code == TVN_ITEMEXPANDED) {
        TVITEM item = nmtv->itemNew;
        item.stateMask = TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;

        if (nmtv->action == TVE_COLLAPSE) {
            item.state = INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(4);
        }
        else if (nmtv->action == TVE_EXPAND) {
            item.state = INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(5);
        }

        TreeView_SetItem(pnl_tree.GetTreeview(), &item);
    }
}
```

Some other links for future treeview image state newcomers, that don't apply to this problem specifically, but helped me slowly figure this thing out:

[Treeview Item States Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760017%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[TVN_ITEMEXPANDED message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)